# How to Bulk-Add Azure endpoints?

Tags: azure, tcp, endpoint, azure-virtual-machine

I've got an FTP server running on Azure. I had to manually add in 20 endpoints for the 'data' connection.

*It was painful.*

[image: Why is it so hard!!!]

Surely there's a better way to bulk add endpoints to an Azure VM, somehow? If so, could someone list some instructions? I'm open to anything.

eg. I would love to create

`TCP public port 61020 - private port 61020`

to

`TCP public port 61100 - private port 61100`

hmmm....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with PowerShell. A just tested script:

```
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Your_Subscription_Name"
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "CloudServiceName" -Name "VM_Name"
for ($i=6100; $i -le 6120; $i++)
{
    $EndpointName = "FtpEndpoint_"
    $EndpointName += $i
    Add-AzureEndpoint -Name $EndpointName -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort $i -LocalPort $i -VM $vm
}
$vm | Update-AzureVM
```

The actuall service call is performed at bulk when you execute the `Update-AzureVM`

Starting point for Azure PowerShell reference [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495236.aspx).

I am sure you can achieve the same result also with the [XPLAT-CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat).

Comment: did you mean `Select-AzureSubscription` instead of `Set-` ?

Comment: The script definitely works with `Set-AzureSubscription`. But now that you say it, this line might not be even needed.

Comment: I had multiple subscriptions so i had to manually select it. set didn't seem to do anything...

Comment: I also have multiple. but probably the VM I was working with was in the "default" one - just updated the script with `Select-` instead of `Set-`

Answer (score 0):

Note that with the last batch of updates (May 2014) you can now map a fixed Public IP to a VM and avoid needing to use cloud service End Points completely.  This preview feature requires you to provision a new VM to take advantage of it.  The latest Azure PowerShell (0.8.2) also includes the necessary cmdlets to make this work.

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName EastUSVIP -Label "Reserved VIP in EastUS" -Location "East US" 

New-AzureVM -ServiceName "MyApp" -VMs <vm> -Location "East US" -VNetName VNetUSEast -ReservedIPName EastUSVIP
```

The above sample comes from Scott Guthrie's announcement here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/05/12/azure-vm-security-extensions-expressroute-ga-reserved-ips-internal-load-balancing-multi-site-to-site-vpns-storage-import-export-ga-new-smb-file-service-api-management-hybrid-connection-service-redis-cache-remote-apps-and-more.aspx