# Open a starting port and ending port

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

On Windows Azure, how to make it so that for a Windows Server VM, you can add a lot of ports at the same time (ports 150-179) instead of manually adding them one by one. This is possible in AWS, but I can't seem to find it in Azure.

Comment: While you can't specify start/end port, you *can* easily create a set of endpoints in bulk and, with a simple loop, you can do what you're looking for - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677255/how-to-bulk-add-azure-endpoints (which I marked this a duplicate of) to see the answer.

Comment: Thank you David, seemed to work.